# How to get soci.h?

Tags: installation

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, and I compiled a package for object recognition(rein).I got an error indicating that I don't have soci.h:

```
Error: cannot find SOCI header file: soci.h
```

I tried to use this command to install libsoci

```
sudo apt-get install libsoci-core-gcc
```

But I get the message:

```
E: can't find package libsoci-core-gcc
```

Does anybody know how to install this library?Thanks!

P.S.For more detailed information, [click here](http://answers.ros.org/question/39495/how-to-solve-error-cannot-find-soci-header-file-socih/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest ubuntu for which there is a libsoci-core-gcc packages seems to be natty (11.04). These old packages seem to install ok on 12.04, so this is a (very hacky) way of getting `/usr/include/soci/soci.h`:

```
curl -O http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/soci/libsoci-core-gcc_3.0.0+cvs20081223-4build2_amd64.deb
curl -O http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/soci/libsoci-core-gcc-dev_3.0.0+cvs20081223-4build2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg --install libsoci-core-gcc_3.0.0+cvs20081223-4build2_amd64.deb libsoci-core-gcc-dev_3.0.0+cvs20081223-4build2_amd64.deb
```

A perhaps cleaner way would be to build soci from sources: [soci.sourceforge.net](http://soci.sourceforge.net/) and install to your home directory or /usr/local, but that is also more work.

Answer (score 2):

Since Ubuntu Xenial Xerus (16.04) you can use this:

```
sudo apt-get install libsoci-dev
```

to install SOCI and dependencies.